# Asynchronous sqlserver

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp-classic

how can i use Asynchronous queries in sqlserver 2005 & asp (not .net)

Comment: Please support your question with example or any case.

Comment: Can you tell your exact issue. As this is not possible to call Sql Server query Async. 

You can't call and take response more than one from sql server to your c# code. 
Better way is to go with ajax jquery. It will solve your  problem.

If you will share your issue, we can help you more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

ADO connection and recordset support asynchronous behavior, (look at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190988) and [this](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/how-do-i-prevent-my-asp-pages-from-waiting-for-backend-activity.html)), however if your query returns data to the client, it may not make sense to use async behavior. You should consider using AJAX on the HTML side to launch queries and poll for results.

Answer (score 0):

You have a good solution for SQL Server asynchronous queries documented with examples, use cases, etc., here:

https://www.cesarzea.com/czAsyncSQLServer

With that solution, that is an asynchronous call:

```
 EXEC st_czAsyncExecInvoke
         @sentence = 'exec st_proc1 123'
```

It lets you more complex calls. Go to the link to see more cases.